# Pagination on careers goes to blank page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

So, I was browsing careers.stackoverflow.com on my Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m, and later on Firefox 17.0.1 and I found that if open job listing for specific location or keyword, and after try to go to the next page using pagination, i will receive a blank page. But if I hit refresh this blank page loads perfectly after that.

right now i can reproduce this on this page, if i try to click on any page in the pagination

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/java?pg=7

interestingly enough, i cannot reproduce it on IE9

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome (Stable)

Comment: Indeed, here too. Interestingly enough, the developer tools' Network tab shows that the full source was loaded, as well as all dependencies (stylesheets, scripts, images, etc). It's just the displaying that throws a hick-up.

Comment: IE9 doesn't support `pushState`, so it's spared from the borked response that comes back from the AJAX request that's made to load the next page. Presumably the returned view should be just a container of the next page of listings, instead of the full page that comes back now...

Comment: Confirmed. We're looking into this.

Comment: Works fine on Safari 6.0.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting - this issue is now fixed!